# Synonyms, Outer Joins, Single Row String Functions

Tags: mysql, oracle

How do I  Return the order id’s and the total sum of quantities from each order in the order details table. Label the total value as "Total qtys" and return only the orders that had total quantities > 250 and Sort this one on total quantities from highest to lowest?

Comment: what database engine

Comment: What query or queries have you tried? Can you paste the schema of the relevant tables?

Comment: quantities of what? item qty's in detail, or the qty of Order Detail line item rows (probably the first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is for mysql. assuming you are referring to sum(qty)

### schema / load data test

```
create table orders
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    custId int not null 
    -- etc etc
    -- fk to customer id
);

create table orderDetails
(   
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    orderId int not null,
    itemId int not null,
    qty int not null,
    -- etc etc
    -- fk to items table not shown in the example

    -- fk constraint to orders table below: 
    CONSTRAINT fk_orddet_ords FOREIGN KEY (orderId) REFERENCES orders(id)
);

insert orders (custId) values (1),(2),(3);
insert orderDetails (orderId,itemId,qty) values (1,1,9),(2,1,190),(2,1,100),(3,1,255);

-- the below shows that the fk constraint fails for faulty data (orderId 4 does not exist)
insert orderDetails (orderId,itemId,qty) values (4,1,9);
```

### The query

If you don't do the **inr** then id 2 won't show up (that is if you just do a join where qty>250). Not that there aren't smarter minds out there but here is mine:

```
select id,custId,qty from 
(select o.id,o.custId,sum(d.qty) as qty
from orders o
join orderDetails d
on d.orderId=o.id
group by o.id,o.custId) inr
where inr.qty>250
order by qty desc

+----+--------+------+
| id | custId | qty  |
+----+--------+------+
|  2 |      2 |  290 |
|  3 |      3 |  255 |
+----+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: There are some minor improvements that needs to be fixed drew. The query i put in was.                                                                                                              select ORDERID,customerId,qty from 
(select o.ORDERID,o.CUSTOMERID,sum(d.QUANTITY) as qty
from orders o
join orderDetails d
ON d.orderid= o.ORDERID
group by o.ORDERID,o.CUSTOMERID) inr
where inr.qty>250
order by qty desc                                                                                                                              this worked for me